# How should be the size of all files for full installation of vendors in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I am really confused that with the latest developement version of symfony with all applications and code how should be the size of it.

I have two instalation one is around 150MB and other is around 500MB.

I am really not able to find why is there any diff.

Both sites are working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Size may really vary in case if you use `assets:install` without `--symlink` flag.

But for project deployment copies instead of symlinks should be used. So, the total size of your project really depends on the amount of assets (images, videos etc) you have in your Bundles.